# Group by year descending, order by month and total on another column Linq query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Have this Linq query almost working, can't figure out how to do the descending order. Here is what I have so far:

```
list.GroupBy(grp => grp.year)
    .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(grp => grp.month))
    .ToList();
```

Which produces the following results:

[image: Partially Working Output]

Month is in the correct order except the year needs to be in descending order. Like this:

[image]

This might be too much to ask but also need to run a total of days per grouped year. Really appreciate any help!

The data looks like this:

[image]

The answer the worked for me was this:

```
list.OrderByDescending(grp => grp.year).ThenBy(grp => grp.month).ToList()
```

Comment: Add `.ThenByDescending(grp => grp.year)` after the initial order by.

Comment: Isn't there an `OrderByDescending`? You can use the autocomplete feature to see available LINQ methods.

Comment: He wants to order by Month first, and then by Year.

Comment: Can you provide information on what the data in your initial `list` looks like?

Comment: What is the item type in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two comments:

1. You are "grouping" your data, then turning around and un-grouping via a `SelectMany`, which effectively throws away any grouping; it just puts the data into groups, but not in any configurable order.  Just select all of your data in one go, ordering by year descending, then month:

   ```
   list.OrderByDescending(l => l.year)
       .ThenBy(l => l.month));
   ```
2. Adding "group footers" to show subtotals is the job of the presentation layer, not the data layer.  You *could* create a hybrid list that inserts a total "row" into your data, but it is probably more straightforward to add a group footer by configuring whatever control is presenting the data rather than inserting subtotals into the raw data.

Comment: 1. Thank you it works perfect, simple code. 2. Yes, will do the counts on the front end.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `.ThenByDescending(grp => grp.year)`  after your `OrderBy` expression, so like this:

```
list.GroupBy(grp => grp.year)
    .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(grp => grp.month).ThenByDescending(grp => grp.year))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: ThenByDeceding(grp => grp.year) seems to be ignored

Comment: There was a minor formatting change; the current code should do it.

Comment: I know last time you had double dots in there but I saw it. Still ThenByDesceding part is being ignored. Year go from 1980, 1981, 1982 etc. And it should be 1982, 1981, 1980 etc

Comment: There was also a parenthesis misplaced, so the ordering was being applied to the result of `SelectMany` rather than to the result of `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, first, **OrderBy** Year, **ThenBy** Month

See code below:

```
list.OrderByDescending(grp => grp.year).ThenBy(grp => grp.month)
    .GroupBy(grp => grp.year)
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .ToList();
```

If you want to get total days per grouped year, you can do this like that:

```
list.OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Year).ThenBy(grp => grp.Month)
    .GroupBy(grp => grp.Year)
    .Select(g => new { Year = g.Key, Months = g, TotalDays = g.Sum(d => DateTime.DaysInMonth(d.Year, d.Month)) })
    .ToList();
```

So you will have a collection of object that have 3 properties

1. Year
2. Months that is a collection of dates
3. TotalDays that is the total of days from this grouped year

Comment: The ordering is now correct, still working on the totals.